# Removing Affiliate code from google analytics - android sdk

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using enhanced e-commerce to track all purchases. We are not setting any affiliate code in the ProductAction object. But still in the GA dashboard all transactions are shown in affiliate code with the value as "not-set". Is there any way to remove/disable the affiliate code tracking for enhanced e-commerce purchases?